# how to stop page getting refresh on validating form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i'm trying to validate my form using javascript. so when i leave all the fields empty and press submit button i got an error message for the first field, then i add value to the first field and leave rest of the field empty then click the submit button the page got refresh, i'm not getting error message for rest of the input field.

```js
function validate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("InputName").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
  var number = document.getElementById("Inputnumber").value;
  var subject = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
  var message = document.getElementById("Message").value;

  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
    return false;
  }
  if (!isNaN(name)) {
    document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "*Enter valid name*";
    return false;
  }
  if (email == "") {
    document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (number == "") {
    document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
    number.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (number.length != 10) {
    document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "*Enter valid 10 digit number*";
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "*Enter valid 10 digit number*";
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (subject == "") {
    document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
    return false;
  }
  if (message == "") {
    document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form role="form" id="contact_form" name="contactForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputName">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" name="userName" placeholder="Your name">
    <p id="error1"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Your email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="userEmail" placeholder="Your email">
    <p id="error2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputnumber" name="userNumber" placeholder="Phone number">
    <p id="error3"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Subject</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="userSubject" placeholder="Subject">
    <p id="error4"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputMesaagel">Your messsage</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Your message" name="userMessage" rows="4"></textarea>
    <p id="error5"></p>
  </div>
  <p id="error"></p>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-green" name="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
</form>
```

Comment: It is because of `email.focus();` variable `email` is value not DOM element

Comment: Also NEVER call anything "submit" in a form. You will regret it when you try to submit it using JS.

Comment: Also your subject is also type=email. Your validation actually does not run in chrome at all because the HTML5 validation gets in before.

Comment: Also you are trying to make name a number and fail if it is not

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that you have a duplicate id of 'InputEmail' for subject and value. This is invalid html and could cause unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your js code

```js
 function validate() {
   var name = document.getElementById("InputName");
   var email = document.getElementById("InputEmail");
   var number = document.getElementById("Inputnumber");
   var subject = document.getElementById("InputSubject");
   var message = document.getElementById("Message");

   if (name.value == "") {
     document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
     return false;
   }
   if (!isNaN(name.value)) {
     document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "*Enter valid name*";
     return false;
   }
   if (email.value == "") {
     document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
     email.focus();
     return false;
   }
   if (number.value == "") {
     document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
     number.focus();
     return false;
   }
   if (number.value.length != 10) {
     document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "*Enter valid 10 digit number*";
     email.focus();
     return false;
   }
   if (isNaN(number.value)) {
     document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "*Enter valid 10 digit number*";
     email.focus();
     return false;
   }
   if (subject.value == "") {
     document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
     return false;
   }
   if (message.value == "") {
     document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML = "*required fields*";
     return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<form role="form" id="contact_form" name="contactForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputName">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" name="userName" placeholder="Your name">
    <p id="error1"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Your email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="userEmail" placeholder="Your email">
    <p id="error2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputnumber" name="userNumber" placeholder="Phone number">
    <p id="error3"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputSubject" name="userSubject" placeholder="Subject">
    <p id="error4"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputMesaagel">Your messsage</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Your message" name="userMessage" rows="4"></textarea>
    <p id="error5"></p>
  </div>
  <p id="error"></p>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-green" name="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
</form>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can set do this:

```
validate(event){
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

it will prevent the form from submitting .

or

```
validate(){

//...your code 

return false;
}
```